Next.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind') when using headers() in production
I'm working on a Next.js application and using headers() to retrieve the user's IP address in a server component. It works fine in development mode (npm run dev), but after building (npm run build) and starting the app (npm run start), I encounter this error: ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
This error points to the await headers() function in my getIP.ts utility file.
Here’s a simplified version of my setup:
File Structure:

src/app/page.tsx

"use server"
import { getIP } from "./_util/getIP";

export default async function Home() {
  const ip = await getIP();
  return (
    <h1>TEST IP {ip}</h1>
  );
}


src/app/_util/getIP.ts

"use server"
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export async function getIP() {
  const requestHeaders = await headers(); // this line generate the error
  const remoteIP = requestHeaders.get("x-forwarded-for")?.split(":").pop() || "unknown";
  return remoteIP;
}

Steps to reproduce:

Run npm run build
Run npm run start
Access the app

The error occurs when accessing headers() in production.
The repository is available here for reference: GitHub Repo
Things I've tried

I confirmed that getIP is only called server-side.
Removed the await on headers() to test if it’s related to async handling
Checked the Next.js documentation and various GitHub issues but couldn't find a related solution.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with headers() in production mode? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
